# about JNI in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Error log:

```
D/dalvikvm( 1010): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.mediatek.cmmb.app/lib/libcmmbsp.so 0x4051bb80

W/System.err( 1010): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1346]:    86 cannot locate '_ZN7android7RefBase14moveReferencesEPvPKvjRKNS_22ReferenceConverterBaseE'...

W/System.err( 1010): at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:425)
```

libcmmbsp.so can run well in 4.0 platform. But it has the error in platform 2.3. Is it because versions problem? I think so library won’t have the problem because of versions. And I can not find so sound code.

Comment: You should specify to ndk-build platform compatible with the min SDK defined in your ApplicationManifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't locate the function

```
android::RefBase::moveReferences(void*, void const*, unsigned int, android::ReferenceConverterBase const&)
```

because that function wasn't introduced until Android 4.0.

This is an internal library function, not part of the NDK.  Nothing should use this except for code internal to the Android platform itself.  It may disappear, change signature, or change behavior in a future release.

Comment: that's to say if it not has sound code, this app and the set of so is invalid in android2.3?

Comment: The fact that `libcmmbsp.so` depends on a private Android function is a problem.  The library should be built in a way that it only depends on symbols exposed by the NDK.  The .so won't load on anything pre-ICS, and may not work on future releases.